# Changing the color of an editText label, android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I change the color of an editText label with java code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Comment: Do you mean a TextView, which is usually used as a label for an EditText (textbox)? Or the color of text being input in an EditText?

Comment: I mean the textview label of the edittext

Comment: In that case, hawaii.five-O's answer below should work. i.e. someTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following methods for change background or font color.

```
setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```